# Can someone help record a specific radio signal at a specific time to help solve a radio based puzzle?

Tags: jargon

I'm not a radio expert and I've never posted on this forum before.  My request might also seem odd but hopefully someone can help me.  I am pretty much a total layman on this subject so will probably be using terms that sound common to people here and I've little understanding of.  Not even sure what tags to use (and as someone with a decent rep elsewhere on Stack Exchange I know this can be a problem to some)

I'm involved with the hobby of Geocaching, incase you've not heard of it its a global treasure hunting game using GPS coordinates to find hidden containers. In some cases the hiders construct elaborate puzzles for the solver to crack to reveal where a container is hidden. The puzzle I'm trying to crack has been unsolved for almost 7 years with no one finding it.

The puzzle has a theme of Cold War espionage, I've found various recordings on line of Morse code that I've translated. There are also several recordings which simulate Soviet radio stations and numbers stations. The morse code I've deciphered also refers to broadcasts happening at specific times on specific days. I've also got various frequencies in Kilocycles per second and metre band.

So if possible could you let me know the following?   ( I know stack overflow people like separate questions on separate threads but as it's all related closely seems better than explaining myself multiple times)

1) Is it actually possible for an amateur to set up some kind of radio broadcast to run at specific times which would then run indefinitely for the past 7 years like a Numbers Station?

2) The messages I've decoded include the following

> Broadcasts in English this Saturday and Sunday at 10.30 pm 0.30am GMT on 665 1106 1554 7190 9530 9665 9735 and 9745 kilocycles per second. At 8.30 am GMT the broadcast is also transmitted on 7320 and 9520 kilocycles per second. '

I've tried listening using the GlobalTuners website listening from a radio in Teeside.  I'm convinced i can faintly here morse code being broadcast for two minutes at those times.  My friends think I'm imagining it (possibly because I want it to be true)

3) Other information I've got refers to

> You can hear our transmission everyday at at 13 hours GMT and the 13, 16, 19 and 25 meter band.

I've also got coordinates for specific locations in Scarborough, UK in another clue. (these are not where I'm trying to find the geocache) Is it possible that I need to pick up some kind of amateur radio enthusiast signal at those locations at that time?

If anyone can give me any advise and say "yes, this sounds like its possible and an amazing puzzle, let us help get a recording of the message" or "No what your suggesting is impossible" that would be great!

Ultimately is it possible for someone close to Scarborough to get a recording during this time?    I'm this close to buying a radio that can record and getting train there one weekend and hoping I'm right but want to check with people who know the subject first.

Answer (score 4):

The transmissions quoted most likely are not occurring. The quantity of frequencies is suspicious for any broadcasting service and some of the frequencies themselves are not suitable for broadcasting purposes. Also consider that the significant financial commitment needed to maintain such a broadcast regime for all these years, even on one frequency, makes such a scheme dubious.

Further, all western countries heavily regulate frequency usage with an expensive and difficult licensing process. This further precludes the possibility of any GC enthusiast supporting such a broadcast scheme. Licensed amateur radio operators cannot legally use most of the quoted frequencies and we are generally not allowed to make third party "broadcasts" of this type.

My GC senses say that given the string of numbers in your decoded messages, perhaps what you are looking for is already in your hand...